# Incrementally iterating through a dataframe column n times in R

Tags: r

So firstly, please forgive my ignorance with R. I'm still pretty new to it.

I have created a mock dataset, df, for an experiment that I will perform in the next few days. The data will look something like this:

```
well time area
a1  0   100
a1  8   88
a1  16  78
a1  24  33
a2  0   96
a2  8   91
a2  16  69
a2  24  41
a3  0   98
a3  8   60
a3  16  24
a3  24  2
a4  0   89
a4  8   63
a4  16  49
a4  24  27
...
```

Where "well" is the sample id, "time" is the time during the experiment, and "area" is the area of the object I'm to measure. I want to determine, for each well at each time point (0, 8, 16, 24), how much the area measured has changed relative to the initial area **of that well** at time 0.

To do this, I want to add a column to the dataframe titled "percent_initial_size". In this column, I need to calculate the percentage of the initial measured area (at time 0) at each time point. The generic formula would look like this:

```
(area_at_timeX/area_at_time0)*100
```

To help clarify what I'm trying to do, here's how I'd like the dataset to look:

```
well time area percent_initial_size
a1  0   100 100
a1  8   88  88
a1  16  78  78
a1  24  33  33
a2  0   96  100
a2  8   91  94.79
a2  16  69  71.88
a2  24  41  42.71
a3  0   98  100
a3  8   60  61.22
a3  16  24  24.49
a3  24  2   2.04
a4  0   89  100
a4  8   63  70.79
a4  16  49  55.06
a4  24  27  30.34
...
```

Thus, for rows 2-5 in df$percent_initial_size, I need to reference a single value in df$area, row 2 (the area at time 0). Then, for rows 6-9 in df$percent_initial_size, I need to reference df$area row 6 (also the area at time 0). I'm trying to write a script to follow this pattern until the end of my dataset, which will be roughly 500 rows. Hopefully this makes sense.

I know some basic packages (dplyr, tidyr, reshape2, etc.), but I'm at a loss for how to do this. I've tried several ways of tackling this problem, but I'm just not familiar enough with R to figure it out completely. Is there anyone that could help with this, or at least direct me to some documentation that might help? I'm not sure if I can do what I want to do while the data is in the format, or if I need to reformat the dataframe, do my calculations, then convert it back into the original format for plotting in ggplot2. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(dat)[,percent_initial_size:=area/area[1]*100,by=well]
 dat
    well time area percent_initial_size
 1:   a1    0  100           100.000000
 2:   a1    8   88            88.000000
 3:   a1   16   78            78.000000
 4:   a1   24   33            33.000000
 5:   a2    0   96           100.000000
 6:   a2    8   91            94.791667
 7:   a2   16   69            71.875000
 8:   a2   24   41            42.708333
 9:   a3    0   98           100.000000
10:   a3    8   60            61.224490
11:   a3   16   24            24.489796
12:   a3   24    2             2.040816
13:   a4    0   89           100.000000
14:   a4    8   63            70.786517
15:   a4   16   49            55.056180
16:   a4   24   27            30.337079
```

To use the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
dat%>%group_by(well)%>%mutate(percent_initial_size=area/area[1]*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  # perform operations separately for each well
  group_by(well) %>%
  # make sure time zero is in the first position
  arrange(time) %>%
  # divide each area by the first area value for the group (i.e. time zero for the well)
  mutate(percent_initial_size = area / area[1] * 100)
```

The trick to thinking about these problems lies in knowing what is happening in `mutate` expressions. `area` evaluates to a vector just like `df$area` would do in a normal context, and you can do all sorts of R manipulations as long as the final result is the same length as the input.

The exception here is that the previous `group_by` alters it so that the data is split up unto chunks by their `well` value and the mutate expression is evaluated once for each group rather than on the entire data frame all at once. This makes is so that subsetting to the first item of area (`area[1]`) gets the first area in each group, and the `arrange` call makes certain that the first area will be the area for time zero.